# Press Special Key [C_DOWN] 20times in sikuliLibrary

Tags: robotframework

I want to  Press Special Key  "C_DOWN"  20times in sikuliLibrary.
I tried to use these options below. It doesn't work.

- `Press Special Key        C_DOWN (20)`
- `Press Special Key        C_DOWN 20 times`
- `Press Special Key        C_DOWN ,[20]`

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you mention the version of the robot framework, the sikuliLibrary, how you are invoking it (Python or Jython), and so on. It would also be good to clarify if a single keypress works, or only the 20 times part shows a problem. The exact error or problematic behaviour you see would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Sikuli documentation:

http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html

... "Press Special Key" only takes one parameter, the key. C_DOWN looks like a valid key constant per the documentation here:

http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Key.html

The Robot Framework has a FOR loop construct for performing a command multiple times, documented here:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

I would suggest

```
FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    20
    Press Special Key        C_DOWN
END
```

(This is presuming the environment etc is allowing you to execute the Press Special Key directive correctly, as the question isn't completely clear on this point.